# How to connect to gcloud beta sql connect over ssl

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

Once I enable ssl connections for google cloud sql, I can no longer connect to google cloud sql through the cloud shell, I just wanted to make sure I am not missing a command line switch. I get access denied even though username and password are correct.

I can connect fine using mysql client using the ssh keys and granting authorization/whitelisting my IP.

Comment: Can you show us the code you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, the `gcloud sql connect` will not work if you require SSL connectivity.

Consider running the Cloud SQL Proxy locally and using that to connect. This has the benefit of not having to manage SSL certificates and IP authorization manually.